# Retain only values corresponding to true with haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm just learning Haskell and trying to create a retainTrue function which takes a list of elements and a list of booleans, then returns a list of the elements which correspond to the true booleans. So `retainTrue :: [a] -> [Bool] -> [a]`

An example test `retainTrue [1, 2, 3] [True, False, True]` would return `[1, 3]`.

I would typically use filter for this purpose, but the addition of the boolean list is throwing me off. Can anyone recommend an elegant way to tackle this?

Comment: Does [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) help?

Comment: I know zip produces a list of tuples, in this case the first element would be the value and the second element would be the boolean. From there I would need to test if the second (snd) element of the tuple is true and then construct a list containing only the first elements corresponding to true values. I'm just unsure of how to do this in Haskell code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zip` solution alluded to in the comments is:

```
retainTrue :: [a] -> [Bool] -> [a]
retainTrue xs bs = map fst $ filter snd $ zip xs bs
```

The idea is to first inject the extra information from the `[Bool]`, then `filter` based on that extra information, and then drop the extra info (by `map fst`).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it without using `zip`, although it uses the same concept essentially:

```
retainTrue :: [a] -> [Bool] -> [a]
retainTrue [] _ = []
retainTrue _ [] = []
retainTrue (x:xs) (y:ys) = if y then x : f xs ys else f xs ys
```

There is one thing to note here however - the lists need to be of the same length.

This can be written even more concisely as

```
retainTrue (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x|y] ++ f xs ys
```

Of course, you still need to keep the empty list pattern checks.